# how to output 3 cells (<td> </td>) per table row for ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, html-table

Hi all i am trying to display some divs inside table cells(3 cells in one row )using following code but i keep getting incorrect table with missing data. could any one tell me how to fix this problem and display 3 divs per row.Thanks

Here is the image of correct and wrong output:
[image]

Full code with sample data:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

function myFunction()
{

alert("inside function");
var response= "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"1\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 1 \",\r\n   \"Text\": \"\",\r\n   \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/1/102.jpg\",\r\n   \"Note\": null\r\n },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"2\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 2\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/2/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"3\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 3\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/3/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"4\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 4\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/4/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"5\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 5\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/5/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"6\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 6\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/6/102.jpg\",\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"7\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 7\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/7/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"8\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 8\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/8/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"9\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 9\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/9/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  }\r\n]";

var json = $.parseJSON(response);
var html='';
var x=0; // x is number of cells per row maximum 2 cells per row

for(i in json)
{

   // create HTML code
       var div = "<div class=\"image\">\n" + 
       "<a href=\"javascript:doIt('" + json[i].ID + "')\">\n" +
       "<img src=\""+ json[i].ImageUrl +"\"  alt=\"\" />"+ json[i].Title +"\n" +
       "</a>\n" +
       "</div>\n";


if(x<3)
{

//alert("1 value of x is:"+x);
html += '<td>'+div+'</td>\n';

//$('#demo > tbody').append(html );
x=x+1;

}else
{
   //go to next row and print </tr><tr>
//alert("2 value of x is:"+x);
   html += '</tr>\n\n<tr>\n';

$('#demo > tbody').append(html);

x=0;
};

$('#demo > tbody').append(html);

};

};

</script>

</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">

<div class="scroller">

Incorrect :<br>
<table id="demo" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="display: visible;">
  <thead>

      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, openin tag `<tr>` is not added to first `<td>`. You are appending html twice. You need to form correct html then add it to the table after for loop. Also you don't need ';' commas at the end of condition and standart function definition code blocks.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var response = "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"1\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 1 \",\r\n   \"Text\": \"\",\r\n   \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/1/102.jpg\",\r\n   \"Note\": null\r\n },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"2\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 2\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/2/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"3\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 3\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/3/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"4\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 4\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/4/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"5\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 5\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/5/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"6\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 6\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/6/102.jpg\",\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"7\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 7\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/7/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"8\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 8\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/8/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"9\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 9\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/9/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  }\r\n]";

  var json = $.parseJSON(response);
  var html = '';
  var x = 0; // x is number of cells per row maximum 2 cells per row

  for (i in json) {

    // create HTML code
    var div = "<div class=\"image\">\n" +
      "<a href=\"javascript:doIt('" + json[i].ID + "')\">\n" +
      "<img src=\"" + json[i].ImageUrl + "\"  alt=\"\" />" + json[i].Title + "\n" +
      "</a>\n" +
      "</div>\n";


    //alert("x is:"+x);
    div = '<td>' + div + '</td>\n';

    if (x === 0) {
      html += '<tr>' + div;
      x++;
    } else if (x === 1) {
      html += div;
      x++;
    } else if (x === 2) {
      html += div + '</tr>';
      x = 0;
    }

  } //end of for loop

  $('#demo > tbody').append(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <div class="scroller">
    <br>
    <table id="demo" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="display: visible;">
      <thead>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your demo. It solved the problem. Is there a way to make the first cell pre selected with glowing border and make the div images(All the images are 640 by 360 pixels) fit inside each cell completely depending on the width of user device screen(iphone,ipad,tv )?

Comment: may i know why your example above creates empty <tr></tr> between two rows ?

Comment: I forgot to close ```</tr>``` tag and I fixed it. It may cause that bug.

Comment: @user1788736 Here is answer of your second question: https://jsfiddle.net/BekirUzun/q9b4sj8v/

Comment: Many many thanks for answering my questions. Do you think it will place 3 images per rows even on wide screen tvs ? My goal is to keep the same layput as your last jsfiddle on tv screen as well.is that possible? How?

Comment: It will place 3 columns in any screen resolution. That is how table works.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would offer a different solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/wfc9p0e8/

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<style>
  #table{ display: table; width:100%; }
  #table .table-cell { display: inline-table; width:33.33%;  }
</style>

<div class="scroller">

    <div id="table"></div>

</div><!--scroller-->

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

var response= "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"1\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 1 \",\r\n   \"Text\": \"\",\r\n   \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/1/102.jpg\",\r\n   \"Note\": null\r\n },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"2\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 2\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/2/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"3\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 3\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/3/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"4\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 4\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/4/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"5\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 5\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/5/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"6\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 6\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/6/102.jpg\",\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"7\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 7\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/7/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"8\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 8\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/8/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"ID\": \"9\",\r\n    \"Title\": \"title 9\",\r\n    \"Text\": \"\",\r\n    \"ImageUrl\": \"http://awebsite/imagges/9/102.jpg\",\r\n    \"Note\": null\r\n  }\r\n]";

$.each(JSON.parse(response), function(i, value){

  var html = '<div class="table-cell"><div class="image"><a href=javascript:doIt("'+ value.ID +'")><img src="'+ value.ImageUrl +'" alt="'+ value.Title +'"></a></div></div>';

  $('#table').append(html);

  })
})//doc ready

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use a SO snippet instead of a fiddle. Using a snippet helps future proof questions and answers.

Comment: @Matthew Blackett thanks for showing me different method but for my usage all the images are 640 by 360 pixels and your solution will fit 2 image per row without resizing them.My goal is to fit 3 images per row according to width of user device screen size and later allow navigating those images by pressing on keydown.

Comment: You can achieve that with CSS and jquery. IMO it's a little more flexible to do it the way I've done it but it's really what ever you feel most comfortable with/ your needs. @zze noted. Will do in future. New to stack overflow so understanding how best to provide any answers :)